# jsp calling servlet after response not working

Tags: ajax, servlets

I have a dynamic web application . My program is that the user enter a search term , and in response will get list of document containing the term  with check box for each term for the user to check if this document is relevant or not.

My problem is how can I send the checklist values to  my servlet, how is my servlet is going to be called after the first response.  I though of creating another servlet that is going to get the checklist values , but I have no idea
how I am going to call it.

this is bit of my servlet code

```
  String query= req.getParameter("query") ;

          PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

          if(result.isEmpty())
          {out.println("<p> No search result found</p>"); }
          else
          {
          out.println("<table style="+"width:100%"+">");
          out.println("<tr> <td> <p> "+result.size() +"  documents found </p></td>");
          out.println("<td> Relevant </td></tr>");
        for(String word : result.keySet())
              {String regex = "\\b.html\\b";
              String content = word.replaceAll(regex, "");
              out.println("<tr> <td>");
              out.println("<p>");
              out.println(" <a href="+target_dir+"/"+word+">"+content+"</a>");
              out.println("</p>");
              out.println("</td> <td>");
             out.println(" <input type="+"checkbox name="+word+">");
              out.println("</td></tr>");
              }

         out.println( "</table>");}
         // out.println(query);
         out.close();
```

this is a bit of my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
       function sendValues(param){
             xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=callback;
             var  url="servlet"+"?query="+
                document.getElementById("search").value ;
             xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
             xmlHttp.send();
         }
         function callback() {
             if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200) {
                 var value = xmlHttp.responseText;
                 document.getElementById("searchresult").innerHTML = value;
                }
                }
    </script>


</head>
<div id="resultArea"></div>

<body>

<div class="form-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="query"  placeholder="Search for..." required>
    <input type="button" value="search"  id="submit" onclick="sendValues()"/>&nbsp;
</div>
<div class="panel" id="searchresult"> </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

[sample of my output :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMZXX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a button under the results that invokes a function that submits the data for the check-boxes

```
var value = xmlHttp.responseText;
value += '<button type="button" class="relevence">Set Relevant</button>';
document.getElementById("searchresult").innerHTML = value;
```

attach a event listener for the click

```
document.querySelector('#searchresult').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (e.target.className == 'relevence'){
        var arguments = '';
        var checked = document.querySelectorAll('#searchresult :checked');
        var len = checked.length
        if (len == 0) return;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            arguments += checked.getAttribute('name') + '=on&'
        }
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=callback;
        var  url="otherservlet?"+arguments;
        xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlHttp.send();
        function callback() {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200) {
                console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

just loop through the get parameters to get the words that was checked.

===============================================

You forgot the `?` to begin the query string

```
var  url="servlet"+"?query="+
     encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("search").value) ;
```

Comment: It is in my code , I guess I forgot to add it , my problem is after  submit how can I call servlet again to send checklist values ?

Comment: It is still , when I press button set relevant nothing happen